# Active Directory Group Members missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, groups

I'm wondering if anybody could help me with this odd situation:
I've noticed the member count of my active directory groups has missing members when searching from SharePoint.
 I've noticed this when using Audience Targetting and choosing for Active Directory groups. When I search for the groups they show up, but when I look at the member count it shows 0 total members.

This is my current AD configuration:

OU: Sharepoint

- OU:Site1

  - ADGroup1

    - ADMember1
    - ADMember2
    - ADMember3
  - ADGroup2
  - ADGroup3
- OU:Site2
- OU:Site3

When I use Audience Targetting and search for ADGroup, it would show all of the groups, but the ADMember's aren't recognised since it shows 0 Member count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was with the netbios name...
Seems like sharepoint doesn't like a different FQDN/Netbios name.
Example: domain.com --> domaincom\user

Refer to this site to solve the synchronization problem:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18060.sharepoint-20xx-what-if-the-domain-netbios-name-is-different-than-the-fqdn-of-the-domain-with-user-profile.aspx

After an IISreset and recreating the connection it works now.